# Geo query using elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have created and index the same as the example tutorials, in here...

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/geo-point.html

in specific writing the following:

```
curl -PUT 'localhost:9200/my_index?pretty' -d '
{
  "mappings": {
    "my_type": {
      "properties": {
        "location": {
          "type": "geo_point"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

I have also added two points as data

```
curl -PUT 'localhost:9200/my_index/my_type/1?pretty' -d'
{
  "text": "first geo-point",
  "location": { 
    "lat": 41.12,
    "lon": -71.34
  }
}'

curl -PUT 'localhost:9200/my_index/my_type/1?pretty' -d'
{
  "text": "second geo-point",
  "location": { 
    "lat": 41.13,
    "lon": -71.35
  }
}'
```

The example geo bounding box query on the page works (i.e):

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/my_index/_search?pretty' -d'
{
  "query": {
    "geo_bounding_box": { 
      "location": {
        "top_left": {
          "lat": 42,
          "lon": -72
        },
        "bottom_right": {
          "lat": 40,
          "lon": -74
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

But the example from this page (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/query-dsl-geo-bounding-box-query.html) doesn't work:

What I have tried looks like the following:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/my_index/_search?pretty' -d'
{
    "bool" : {
        "must" : {
            "match_all" : {}
        },
        "filter" : {
            "geo_bounding_box" : {
                "my_type.location" : {
                    "top_left" : {
                        "lat" : 42,
                        "lon" : -72
                    },
                    "bottom_right" : {
                        "lat" : 40,
                        "lon" : -74
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

The error I get is as follows:

```
"error" : {
    "root_cause" : [ {
      "type" : "search_parse_exception",
      "reason" : "failed to parse search source. unknown search element [bool]",
      "line" : 3,
      "col" : 5
    } ],
    "type" : "search_phase_execution_exception",
    "reason" : "all shards failed",
    "phase" : "query",
    "grouped" : true,
    "failed_shards" : [ {
      "shard" : 0,
      "index" : "my_index",
      "node" : "0qfvkynhTRyjHFRurBLJeQ",
      "reason" : {
        "type" : "search_parse_exception",
        "reason" : "failed to parse search source. unknown search element [bool]",
        "line" : 3,
        "col" : 5
      }
    } ]
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

I hope its just a simple error, so would like to know what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to specify that the whole thing is a query:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/my_index/_search?pretty' -d'
{
   "query": {
      "bool" : {
          "must" : {
              "match_all" : {}
          },
          "filter" : {
              "geo_bounding_box" : {
                  "my_type.location" : {
                        "top_left" : {
                          "lat" : 42,
                          "lon" : -72
                      },
                      "bottom_right" : {
                          "lat" : 40,
                          "lon" : -74
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
      }
   }
}'
```

However as far as I understand using bool with must and filter is the old way of doing things. In previous versions, geo queries were thought of as "filters", so you had to first run a match_all query to return all the results, and then filter using the geo bounding box. In Elasticssearch 2.0+, there is no separation between filters and queries - everything is a query. So you can run the geo query directly:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/my_index/_search?pretty' -d'
{
  "query": {
    "geo_bounding_box": { 
      "location": {
        "top_left": {
          "lat": 42,
          "lon": -72
        },
        "bottom_right": {
          "lat": 40,
          "lon": -74
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```